# How to speak Brainfuck: for beginners

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, vectors, brainfuck

The following code transforms multi-line input into the the Brainfuck equivalent. One line turns into one program. The resulting programs are split by newlines for readability.

## Brainf.cpp

```
#include "Brainf.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> userInput;
    std::string currentLine = " "; // do not start empty

    while (currentLine.length() != 0) // escape input by an empty line
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, currentLine);
        userInput.push_back(currentLine);
    }

    std::vector<std::string>::size_type userInputSize = userInput.size();

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < userInputSize; i++)
    {
        std::cout << modifyString(userInput[i]) << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## Brainf.hpp

```
#ifndef BRAINF_HPP
#define BRAINF_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string modifyChar(char input, int carry)
{
    std::string output;
    int next = input - carry;
    if (next > 0)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < next; ++i)
        {
            output += "+";
        }
    }
    if (next < 0)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < abs(next); ++i)
        {
            output += "-";
        }
    }
    output += ".";

    return output;
}

std::string modifyString(std::string input)
{
    std::string output;
    int traveller = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
    {
        output += modifyChar(input[i], traveller);
        traveller = (int)input[i];
    }
    return output;
}

#endif
```

## Explanation:

The print statement in Brainfuck is `.`. The resulting Brainfuck prints the original string character-by-character, so there will be as much `.` as there are characters to print. Between those `.` there will be either `+` if the ASCII is higher than the previous character and `-` if it's lower.

The Brainfuck doesn't think. It increments, decrements or prints.

## Example usage:

Input:

```
Hello World!
```

Output:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++..+++.--------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++.------.--------.-----------------------
--------------------------------------------.
```

Input:

```
FizzBuzz
Foo!Bar!
```

Output:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++..----------------------------------
----------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++
..

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..----------------------------------------------
--------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++.-------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------.
```

## Points of concern:

- I'm bad at naming things.
- My user-input handling feels bad.
- There's a cast in my code which feels like a design flaw.
- I may be needlessly repeating myself in one case while not splitting responsibilities far enough in another.
- It's not modular.
- It may not be idiomatic C++11.
- It may not be safe (although IMHO, there's not much which can go wrong).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, let's not beat around the bush. Clearly your filenames should be Brainfuck.hpp and Brainfuck.cpp. Let's not be shy. Now for the real reviews:

**Input**

```
std::string currentLine = " "; // do not start empty

while (currentLine.length() != 0) // escape input by an empty line
{
    std::getline(std::cin, currentLine);
    userInput.push_back(currentLine);
}
```

This is bad. `getline()` could fail - and you'd *expect* it to fail when the input runs out. But you're not checking the result of `getline()`, so you end up writing an extra string onto your vector. The correct approach would be:

```
for (std::string currentLine; std::getline(std::cin, currentLine); ) {
    userInput.push_back(currentLine);
}
```

This ensures that you get the correct strings in your `userInput`.

**Looping**

Since this is tagged C++11, you definitely want to use a range-for expression to do your loop. It's less code and clearer:

```
for (const std::string& str : userInput) {
    std::cout << modifyString(str) << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

**Know what's in the standard**

Your `modifyChar()` function's job is to pick some character (either `+` or `-`) and return a string with that character `next` times, followed by a period. You do **not** need a loop for this. There is a constructor for [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a count and a character and constructs a `string` with that character that many times.

Thus:

```
std::string modifyChar(char input, int carry)
{
    int next = input - carry;
    std::string output = (next > 0) ? std::string(next, '+')
                                    : std::string(-next, '-');
    return output + '.';
}
```

And same comment about looping again for `modifyString`. Though additionally you should take `input` by reference-to-const, to avoid a completely unnecessary copy:

```
std::string modifyString(std::string const& input)
{
    std::string output;
    int traveller = 0;
    for (char c : input)
    {
        output += modifyChar(c, traveller);
        traveller = c;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I knew I was doing something the wrong way around with my input. These are all very valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

### Similar code:

```
if (next > 0)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < next; ++i)
    {
        output += "+";
    }
}
if (next < 0)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < abs(next); ++i)
    {
        output += "-";
    }
}
```

These two snippets are almost identical.  I would combine them like this:

```
char toAppend = next > 0 ? '+' : '-';

for (unsigned i = 0; i < abs(next); ++i)
{
    output += toAppend;
}
```

Also, I would probably just use an `int` unless you really need the larger number size provided by an unsigned `int`, in which case I would probably use a `long`.

---

### Char to Int Cast

```
traveller = (int)input[i];
```

When you assigned a `char` to an `int`, you do not need to cast.  This two statements are the same (although the explicit cast shows you are deliberately doing it):

```
traveller = (int)input[i];
traveller = input [i];
```